# storing line from txt file to string java

Tags: java

My program reads a txt file and shows each line in a Jlabel when the Jbutton is clicked.

When the program runs and the Jbutton is clicked nothing appears in the JLabel.

I believe this is because I am not calling the String line correctly in the readFile method.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver {

        List<String> lines;

        static String line = "";

        static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = "Welcome Students!";
        String b = "Start!";
        private JFrame f;
        private JPanel p;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

        JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

        int i;

        private int clicked;

        public Driver() {
                gui();
        }

        public void gui() {
                lines = readLinesFromFile();
                i = 0;
                f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");
                p = new JPanel();
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                f.add(jl);
                f.add(p);
                p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                p.add(b1);

                jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                // pack the frame for better cross platform support
                f.pack();
                // Make it visible
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setSize(500, 400); // default size is 0,0
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jl.setText(lines.get(i));
                        i++;
                        if ( i > lines.size() ) {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        if (b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")) {
                            b1.setText("Next Question");
                        } else {
                            b1.setText("Click For Answer");
                        }
                    }
                });


            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            if (clicked++ == 10) {

                                    Object[] options = { "No, thanks", "Yes, please" };

                                    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                                                    "Would you like more math questions? ",
                                                    "Math Questions", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                                                    options[1]);

                                    if (response == 1)
                                            clicked = 1; // reset
                                    else
                                            System.exit(0);
                            }
                    }
            }); 
    }


        public static List<String> readLinesFromFile() {
             List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));
                if (scanner.hasNext()){
                    lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return lines;
        }

        private static void readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            scanner.close();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new Driver();
                        readFile(new File("upload.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Not really error related, at least that I know of, but why don't you just create a generic scanner to pass to problems since you load the file again in your problems method.

Comment: Like @zgc7009 said, no need to load the file twice. Otherwise, you're on the right track. I think [this lightweight java debugging guide](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) I wrote will help you. You might also want to fix your indentation, to improve readability.

Comment: You'll also need to make `problems` static if you want to run it from `main` like that.

Comment: the error was cause the way im running problems in main. when I changed it to static it went away but the program compiles with no errors but nothing loads to the gui.

Comment: @zgc7009 will you please show me what you mean? I am dying here trying to figure this out.. I have wrote this 4 times deleted it all and started over. lol I thinking im missing small piece of the puzzle that is java. it just has not clicked with me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the label for the **jl** field with one of the lines from the text file, then you need to do the following:

1. add a List field inside your Driver class:

   ```
   public class Driver {
      List<String> lines;
      //other fields that you need
   }
   ```
2. in the *gui()* method, on the first line, initialize the *lines* field with the actual lines from the file, and initialize *i* counter with 0:

   ```
   public void gui() {
       lines = readLinesFromFile();
       i = 0;
       //other code
   ```
3. add the following method:

   ```
   public static List<String> readLinesFromFile() {
       List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
       try {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));
           if (scanner.hasNext()){
               lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
           }
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return lines;
   }
   ```
4. change the first ActionListener for **b1** with the following:

   ```
     b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               jl.setText(lines.get(i));
               i++;
               if ( i > lines.size() ) {
                   i = 0;
               }
               if (b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")) {
                   b1.setText("Next Question");
               } else {
                   b1.setText("Click For Answer");
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Also, using this implementation, you don't need the *line* variable anymore, because you set the text for the label to one of the values from the *lines* field.

NOTE: if *i* gets higher that the actual number of lines in the file, it is reset to 0. If you don't want this, just change the if block in the ActionListener that checks the size

Comment: Thank you. I edited and added my full program so you could see what I am attempting to do. I need to set the line to the Jlabel. I am doing this by using  jl.setText(line); but the method readFile eclipse says i'm not using the line variable. I appreciate your help would you please look at the new code I added and see if you can see where im going wrong?

Comment: Thanks to be clear. I am trying to run the program and display a message in the label. Then when you click the jbutton it shows the first line in the file, then you click again and it shows the 2nd line and so on. i want it to loop through the lines in the file everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: this line says im not using the scanner varaiale. and when the program loads onclick it shows the first line but does not loop through the other lines no matter how many times I click the button.  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));

Comment: ok i fixed it, i just needed to change Scanner scanner to scanner. But when I run the program it will only show the first line..

Comment: I updated my code, Do you see where the error could be? There is no syntax eror. its just not looping through the next lines.

Comment: @user3298955 I wrote a working version what I think you are trying to achieve. You can find the code at this link -> https://gist.github.com/gabrielruiu/b5e293a98c908995ab92

Comment: If its not too much trouble please upvote the answer as well :), thank you